# Permissions Granting with Action_Call intent at runtime

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

Sending a user to dial screen is pretty straight forward using this code

```
    EditText firstNumber;
    Button btnAdd;
    String hash;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main23);

        btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


                    String text= et.getEditableText().toString();
                    hash = "#";


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:*221*" + text + "hash"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
          }
        }
     });

    }
```

However when I want a user to automatically make a call from a button click the button should auto make a call. I have set it up with  **android.permission.CALL_PHONE**, I use this **code below**....

```
EditText firstNumber;
EditText secondNumber;
Button   btnAdd;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    //assigning where the button5 to btnAdd
    btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

    // set up my setOnClickListener for button
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                //stores whats inside of the editText2 to et and et2
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                EditText et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

                //stores whats been sent to et and et2 variables to text and text2
                String text= et.getEditableText().toString();
                String text2 =et2.getEditableText().toString();


                // new intent to take user to dial screen and make the call automatically.
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*215*" + text + "*" + text2 + "#"));
                callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                // crashes here "i get red squigglies here "
                startActivity(callIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {

          }
        }
    });

}
```

I get a squiggly under **startActivity(callIntent);** stating that "Call requires permission which may be rejected by user. Code to explicitly check to see if the permission is available". how do i make it run at runtime?

Comment: See [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: yes but still i dont understand. please help